# Befriending two Facebook test users

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

Using the Facebook C# SDK, how can you connect two test users?

Everything works just fine when I enter in the commands into my web browser:

To send a friend request from ID_1 to ID_2:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<ID_1>/friends/<ID_2>?method=post@access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN_1>
```

Then for ID_2 to accept ID_1's request:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<ID_2>/friends/<ID_1>?method=post@access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN_2>
```

However, when I try to do this from the Facebook C# api, it fails.

I've tried:

```
dynamic result = client.Get(ID_1 + "/friends/" + ID_2 + "&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN_1");
result = client.Get(ID_2 + "/friends/" + ID_1 + "&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN_2");
```

However, I haven't gotten it two work with the C# sdk.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.